# load language file

Tags: themes, localization, translation

I want to load my French language file into my [Arcade Basic](https://wordpress.org/themes/arcade-basic/) theme. There is a language file, [`arcade.pot`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/arcade-basic/1.0.6/library/languages/arcade.pot), and I translated it using PoEdit. I don't know how to add it, there is a function, in `functions.php`,

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'arcade', BAVOTASAN_THEME_TEMPLATE . '/library/languages' );
```

but i'm not sure how to use it, I try like this,

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'fr_CA', BAVOTASAN_THEME_TEMPLATE . '/library/languages' );
```

`fr_CA.mo` is my language file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to edit functions.php (moreover don't edit this line or it will break the localisation of the theme, because `arcade`, is the code used to know where to search translations)

according to the line you read in functions.php, you have to put fr_CA.mo and fr_CA.po in `wp-content/themes/arcade-basic/library/languages`

Comment: There are there, but they dosen't load.

Comment: I just try with a new installation of WordPress and this theme and it works for me (even with a child theme). have you a cache plugin or another plugin wich can interfer ?

Comment: My plugin : Askimet, Blogger Importer Extended, Blogger To Wordpress, Hello Dolly, Jetpack. Before WP Super Cache was installed, but it's now desactivate. Does the WP lang must be `fr_CA`?

Comment: Sorry, I have rename the two files to `fr_FR` instead of `fr_CA` and the change is instant. Thank you very much. A question : how to download WP in canadian french?

Comment: look here : https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/fr-ca/default/wp/4.2.x --- click on each project then click on "export" at the bottom of the page. et voilà les jolis fichiers :)